# RouteParams in AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, routes

I am trying to pass a routeParam to a $http.get in my Angular controller, but I am not getting data displayed. 
Here is what I have below. Am I not using the $routeParams correctly? 
link to JSON Data is http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchone&&id=50
I need to pass the value of id dynamically.

**Here is my angularJS code:**

```
            var app = angular
        .module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when("/home", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                    controller: "homeController"
                })
                .when("/courses", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/courses.html",
                    controller: "coursesController"
                })

                .when("/students/:id", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/studentDetails.html",
                    controller: "studentDetailsController"
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: "/home"
                })

        })
        .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Home Page";
        })
        .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "ASP.NET", "SQL Server"];
        })

         })
        .controller("studentDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
            $http({
                url: "http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchone&&id=",
                method: "get",
                params: { id: $routeParams.id }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.stud = response.data;

            })
        })
```

**Here is my partial page:**

```
<h1>Student Details</h1>

<table style="border:1px solid black">
<tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>{{stud.id}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>{{stud.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>{{stud.username}}</td>
</tr>

</table>
<h4><a href="#/students">Back to Students list</a></h4>
```

[image: When I load the page, It seems like data is being fetched but somehow not displayed. Please help.]
I checked using ng-inspector, When I load the page, It seems like data is being fetched but somehow not displayed. Please help.

Link to working application is http://enrolin.in/test/#/students/50

Comment: you forgot the array `{{ stud[0].id }}`

Comment: oh yes its working now. But I don't understand, why we need the array.